# Add/Reduce hours/minutes from a Date object in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

As methods like getHours, getMinutes of java.util.Date class are deprecated and java.util.Calendar class is not yet supported in gwt, is there a better way to add/reduce hours/minutes from a Date object in gwt without doing String manipulation.

Comment: Why don't you just use `getHours()`, etc from java.util.Date? They may be deprecated, but they are still present and functional. Especially, as you mention, there's no Calendar support as of yet and that's the preferred alternative.

Comment: Yes, technically it is deprecated in Java but GWT supports it just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
final long SECONDS = 1000;
final long MINUTES = 60*SECONDS;
final long HOURS = 60*MINUTES;

myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + 3*HOURS + 25*MINUTES);
```

But if you **can** use `getHours`/`setHours` and it better fits what you want to do, there's no reason for not doing it. Just because it's documented as *deprecated* is not a compelling reason (for GWT's PoV at least)